# Where does ddev put mysql dump file?

Tags: mysql, ddev

I have setup a simple wordpress website with ddev.

I want to dump my mysql but I can't seem to find it.

When I run the command `ddev export-db` I get this response:

```
// alot of this gibberish:
?.?-O#˛????6?.?’X?ϓQ?%???rFz?yĮ&?Xr??????$?~r=~3x??}?~??5?????3?\?\?>? ?.{0(

// and at the end this message:
Wrote database dump from myproject database 'db' to stdout in gzip format.
```

Problem is I can't seem to find the zip file anywhere, where should it be?

Comment: Please do not use irrelevant tagging - otherwise, please explain how this question is related to Wordpress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`to stdout` is the main point: it's not put anywhere in the file system, but printed to the console. [The documentation](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/users/cli-usage/#exporting-a-database) provides hints about how to use that command properly:

```
ddev export-db --file=/tmp/db.sql.gz
ddev export-db --gzip=false --file=/tmp/db.sql
ddev export-db >/tmp/db.sql.gz
```

Comment: Yea i think i read them but I can't find any flag explanations. if i run the "--file=/tmp/db.sql.gz" I understand it should dump it into that file, but I still cant find that file location

Comment: What have you tried to find that file? I've ran that command, and the file is dumped to that exact location

Comment: i have tried looking for it through the finder on mac and it just doesnt seem to exist

Comment: alright i think i finally found it. It landed into a hidden folder in which the tmp resided in, strange stuff! i finally got onto it by just doing "cd /tmp/" and the mac finder cant seem to find it

Comment: The Finder on Mac by default tries to hide a few directories that are believed to be too sensitive for your average user. As you're in the terminal typing these commands, presumably you are familiar with the `cd` command, so if navigate to a directory such as `/tmp` you can then type `open .` which will open a finder window with that directory exposed. I also believe that Spotlight does not expose files in those directories so they don't appear in gui based searches.